# mysql- GROUP CONCAT error

Tags: mysql, sql, encryption

I have got error while fetching encrypted values in `GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CONCAT('MAX(IF` tag, actually i m trying to get pivot values for table field with different prim key, i have two tables as-

**individual_data**

```
-----------------------------------
|prim_key  |fieldname  |answertext|
-----------------------------------
|30101     |state      |0         |
|30101     |Number     |4         |
|30101     |Name       |Rajbanshi |
|30101     |Main       |RAJBANSHI |
|30101     |Surname    |RAJBANSHI |
|30201     |state      |0         |
|30201     |Number     |4         |
|30201     |Name       |Pawar     |
|30201     |Main       |Ramesh    |
|30201     |Surname    |Pawar     |
-----------------------------------
```

***Note**- here aswertext field is encrypted, for sake of clarity i have given actual values...

and **sms_household** as

```
--------------------------
|hhid  |sampletype  |urid|
--------------------------
|30100 |3           |3008|
|30200 |4           |3005|
--------------------------
```

and want desired result as

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|prim_key |state | number | name      | main      | surname   | sampletype | urid |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   30101 |    0 |      4 | Rajbanshi | RAJBANSHI | RAJBANSHI |          3 | 3008 |
|   30201 |    0 |      4 | Pawar     | Ramesh    | Pawar     |          4 | 3008 |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

for the same i have written the query as

```
SET @@group_concat_max_len = 300000;
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT 
GROUP CONCAT (DISTINCT 
CONCAT(
'MAX(IF(I.fieldname = ''',
fieldname, 
''', convert(aes_decrypt(answertext,'xyz')USING utf8), NULL)) AS ',
fieldname
)
) INTO @sql
FROM individual_data;

SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT I.prim_key "prim_key" H.sampletype "sampletype", H.urid "urid"', @sql,
'FROM individual_data I inner join sms_household H on H.hhid = concat'(left(I.prim_key,4),'0')' and H.hhid like '30%' and H.urid like '30%' GROUP BY I.prim_key');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;`
```

but i got syntax error msg in line `convert(aes_decrypt(answertext,'basbas')USING utf8), NULL)) AS '.....
i am not getting what is wrong..!!

Comment: The `'''` parameter of concat() right before the convert() call seems incorrect to me. `''''` or using char() to get the single quote would be better,

Comment: How come you have duplicated primary key values?!?

Comment: Probably it's a foreign key. This way Manoj can store data in a flexible way for certain records in another table.

Comment: it's just named as prim_key ....don't take meaning...

Comment: That's a bad table design. Make `individual_data` a table with proper columns for state, number, name, etc. Give `sms_household` a prim_key_min and prim_key_max, so you can compare the range without string manipulation. Once done, there won't be any problem to query the data.